# iOS Facebook App Links not working

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, host, applinks

I have been trying to use App Links by Facebook.

I created App Link successfully using Graph Api Exporer and got a canonical url back (e.g. https://fb.me/1234567890). When I post it on my timeline in Facebook and click on it, it tries to open the App store not my App.

1.) Is it necessary to have App Store Id of a live app to test deep linking in iOS?

2.) I have checked from my safari and the url scheme that I have registered is opening successfully my application. e.g. myapp:// opens my application so url scheme is correct. What am I missing ?

3.) I have made sure deep linking option is on in my settings for app on Facebook developer site.

4.) Is there a way I can test deep linking in the iOS simulator?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem you have described here.

Comment: whenever i click on my shared link on FB, my html page opens up and there is a icon on the top of navigation bar, on click of which my app opens. It do not open directly.

Comment: Yes, i do get that too. From reading all the documentation, it seems it should open up automatically or at least get a prompt. I tried with pinterest and it gives a prompt.

Comment: I'm having exactly same problems. Anyone figured this out?

Comment: Any progresses yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your website meta data and the Facebook iOS app will open your app directly...

```
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
```

If that doesn't work then you still have other issues with your meta data. Best way to debug is to go to [developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) and type in your url and select 'Show existing scrape information'. If there are any errors it won't work.  Fix the problems and hit the 'Fetch new scrape information' button. Then kill the Facebook iOS app and relaunch it. Then the AppLink will work as expected next time you press the item in the FB feed.